# Retrieving max element from SortedSet

Tags: ruby

I found `SortedSet#max`, but it seems to be O(N). For now I would do something like this:

```
s = SortedSet.new((1..100000).to_a.reverse)
```

where `reverse` is just to make sure.

```
min_element = nil; s.each { |x| min_element = x; break }
```

For maximum element, I would build another `SortedSet` with all values multiplied by `-1` and do the same thing. Is there a more conventional way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Monkey patch `SortedSet`.

```
class SortedSet
  def max
    @keys[-1]
  end

  def min
    @keys[0]
  end
end
```

That's O(1).

Comment: Looks really nice!
But I am figuring why I get the following error:
`max: undefined method [] for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: If the `Set` is empty, you'll have neither min or max, and that's why you have the above error.

Comment: I have no idea why, but it seems like only after calling SortedSet#first, it works without showing any error. Anyway, that was a huge help, thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to spot it, too. Give me some time please.

Comment: @DatNguyen I am quite sure it isn't supposed to be empty, and at least it doesn't work without anyhow calling `first`. This is the link to the [code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ba53f2d3da49cab6e9b8c0d8c845196d).

Comment: Looks like the `@keys` are lazily generated. After I `inspect` the set, the `@keys` are available, and that's why `@keys` are always available in `irb`, but not so in a script file.

Comment: Is it possible to make sure that the `@keys` are solidly generated without dropping efficiency, after every operation applied on it?

Comment: It seems impossible, because whenever an element is added to/removed from the set, the `@keys` is reset to `nil`.

Comment: There's another instance variable, `@hash`, which is eagerly loaded. But retrieving keys from it takes O(n) time.